# Hibernate - Parameter value [2011] was not matching type [java.lang.Integer]. How to solve?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jql

I am getting the message above even though the value I'm passing through an Integer to the named query.
Can anyone explain why?
Thanks

DAO Java Code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(interval.getStartDate());        
query.setParameter("academicYear", new Integer(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
```

Query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "StudentDemographics.findByMOEDEqual", query = "SELECT s.student FROM StudentDemographics s " +
            "WHERE :academicYear = s.academicYear " +
            "AND UPPER(s.MOED) like :MOED"),
```

Error:
Parameter value [2011] was not matching type [java.lang.Integer]

Environment is Spring w Hibernate/JQL + SQL Server

Comment: What's the type of academicYear field in the StudentDemographics?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and could fix it this way:

I used **long instead** of **int** as a **type** for the respective field.