# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException with java persistance API

Tags: spring, jpa

I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` similar to the link given below.To solve it I tried to change the field type from Integer to Long. But still I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [5] was not matching type [com.buddhiedge.server.entity.StudyplanCategory]
```

StudyplanCategory is the entity class.

The problem is similar to the one in the below link.
[Hibernate - Parameter value [2011] was not matching type [java.lang.Integer]. How to solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622882/hibernate-parameter-value-2011-was-not-matching-type-java-lang-integer-ho)
My entity Class is:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "studyplanCategoryList", "dropboxzipfile",
        "parentCategory", "createdDate", "updatedDate" })
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name", "status", "sptTutorialsList" })
@Entity
@Table(name = "studyplan_category", catalog = "buddhiedgeserver_db", schema = "", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "dropboxzipfile" }) })
@NamedQueries({

        @NamedQuery(name = "StudyplanCategory.findSubStudyPlanById", query = "SELECT s FROM StudyplanCategory s WHERE s.parentCategory=:parentCategory order by updatedDate DESC")})

    public class StudyplanCategory implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
        private Long id;

    }
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code/types, and the complete error message.

Comment: Have given the complete error message.Please help.

Comment: Please post your entity code.

Comment: Well, what about the code? The query? Why do you expect your ORM to be able to map "5" to a StudyplanCategory"?

Comment: Hi, I have added the entity class this is the named query.@NamedQuery(name = "StudyplanCategory.findSubStudyPlanById", query = "SELECT s FROM StudyplanCategory s WHERE s.parentCategory=:parentCategory order by updatedDate DESC")}). The field parentcategorey is to be passed where the exception is thrown.Please help.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code and included only the relevent part. please check.The field id is showing problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are passing `5` as parameter to the query. If you want to pass an ID rather than an entity, change the query to:

```
WHERE s.parentCategory.id=:parentCategoryId
```

Comment: Ok.But parentCategory is field in the database. Not an object.

Comment: Hi Like this,@JoinColumn(name = "parentCategory", referencedColumnName = "id")
 @ManyToOne
 private StudyplanCategory parentCategory;

Comment: exactly. So it _is_ an object. HQL queries refer to your entity model, not your database.

Comment: Hi, i tried to change the query like this as you suggested but it throws a Null Pointer Exception because of which the server fails to start.@NamedQuery(name = "StudyplanCategory.findSubStudyPlanById", query = "SELECT s FROM StudyplanCategory s WHERE s.parentCategory.id=:parentCategory.id order by updatedDate DESC")})

Comment: hi I again changed to WHERE s.parentCategory.id=:parentCategory.id Now the server starts but org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [parentCategory] on trying to exexute this query. Please check.

Comment: the parameter name should be `parantCategoryId`, and it should be passed as such to the query.

Comment: Hi,The server is not starting up because of errors in namedQuery after I changed like that.

Comment: well, fix the errors.. I don't know how is everything called in your model, but it should be pretty striaghtforward. Use object fields rather than column names, and placeholder names should be without any dots.

Comment: Yes,that was the problem. I fixed when I started passing parantCategory (object) rather than id (long and int). But I wonder why it s designed like that.Beacause I have to an object here instead of a field.